# Returning last result set from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Stored procedure `a`  is calling another procedure `b` and `b` has two out parameter and also a result set with select statement. Now I want to return result set from `a` with select statement but when I execute `a` it shows two result sets, first from `b` and then from `a`.

So how to get result set of just `a`? Please I don't want to store result of `b` into temp table.  thanks.

```
a usp_Save_IssuancePcsStToSt 
b usp_Stitcher_Stock_Form
```

details of b

```
    @st_code smallint, 
    @QltyCode varchar(30),
    @ColorCode varchar(6),
    @NetPieces int = NULL out ,
    @NetWeight numeric(13,4) = NULL out
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @rowNum int= 0;

    SELECT 
        @rowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY st_code, quality_code, o_color_code), 
        @NetPieces = ISNULL(SUM((rec_pcs + adj_plus_pcs + reopen_pcs)- (issued_pcs + adj_minus_pcs + re_packing_pcs+ return_pcs)), 0),
        @NetWeight = ISNULL(SUM((rec_wt + adj_plus_wt + reopen_wt) - (issued_wt + adj_minus_wt + return_wt + re_packing_wt)), 0.00)
    FROM 
        dbo.v_rpt_cc_transaction_all 
    WHERE 
        doc_date >= '03/02/2014' 
        AND st_code = @st_code
        AND quality_code = @QltyCode
        AND o_color_code = @ColorCode
    GROUP BY 
        st_code, quality_code, o_color_code

    SELECT @rowNum AS SerialNumber, ISNULL(@NetPieces, 0) AS net_pcs , ISNULL(@NetWeight, 0.00) AS net_wt
```

Comment: If you don't want temporary tables, either split your SP in 2 different ones or conditionally (by parameter) return a result set or the other.

Comment: its already used at five diiferent places(insided sp's) and we are at uat will be live in next week don't want to take risk of splitting or chaninging at all diferent places.

Comment: Changed Stored Procedure `b` to based on a input parameter (like `@show_result`) to conditionally return the result. You may default the value of `@show_result` to `true` . When `a` call `b`, pass in `false` to `@show_result`

Comment: conditionally (by parameter) return a result set or the other. pease explain a bit @APC

Comment: `if @show_result = 1 SELECT @rowNum AS SerialNumber...`

Comment: its means again i have to make changes at all places where i used  **b**  because of new input parameter @Squirrel

Comment: Considering these are all all scalar values, why not use `OUTPUT` parameters?

Comment: not necessary.  As i mention earlier, you default the new parameter value to `true` so the result will be shown by default.

Comment: *"pease explain a bit"* Umm not my comment, you meant @EzLo

Comment: yes that is for Ezlo but @APC do we have any functionality that we only return our  last result set from  different result set. thanks

Comment: @Larnu here we are already getting select statment from our procedure please have a look at procedure B

Comment: Everything in the snippet of an SP you have provided uses scalar value, @MunawarKhan `@rowNum` is a scalar value; so my point stands, why not use an `OUTPUT` parameter?

Comment: @Larnu i am totally agree with you but as i mention in my above comments we are ready to live if i make this chnage and remove select there are place in c# code from where sp is callled and waiting for result that all will be disturbed

Comment: In SP-a, have you tried capturing the results from SP-b into a TABLE variable and then handle the response from SP-a as needed? Capturing the results of SP-b into a table variable will still fire the final SELECT of SP-b, but prevent a second resultset from returning.

Comment: INSERT INTO @TableVar ( cols... )
EXEC SP-b;

Comment: @Critical Error i have this solution already and mention it above i don't wanna use it.